# Handling additional data in Apache ServiceComb compensation methods

Tags: java, apache, microservices, rollback, distributed-transactions

I'm currently looking at the implementations of saga pattern for distributed transactions and I found that Apache ServiceComp pack might be something that works for me.

However, I have found a problem that the limitation of compensating methods to have the same declaration as the methods they compensate may be a bottleneck.

From Apache's example:

```
  @Compensable(compensationMethod = "cancel")
  void order(CarBooking booking) {
    booking.confirm();
    bookings.put(booking.getId(), booking);
  }

  void cancel(CarBooking booking) {
    Integer id = booking.getId();
    if (bookings.containsKey(id)) {
      bookings.get(id).cancel();
    }
  }
```

You can see that we have the same declaration for both methods.

But, what if I need additional information to compensate my transaction? For instance, I have a call to external system to update some flag to "true". When I need to compensate it, how do I make "cancel" method know what the original value of this flag was?

The things get more tricky when we update the whole object. How do I send the whole object before modification to the cancel transaction?

These limitation doesn't look quite promising. Do you know if there are approaches to fight with this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save localTxId and flag an in your application and use localTxId in the compensation method to get the flag

```java
  Map extmap = new HashMap();

  @Autowired
  OmegaContext omegaContext;

  @Compensable(compensationMethod = "cancel")
  void order(CarBooking booking) {
    booking.confirm();
    bookings.put(booking.getId(), booking);

    //save flag 
    extmap.put(omegaContext.localTxId(),'Your flag') 
  }

  void cancel(CarBooking booking) {
    //get flag
    extmap.get(omegaContext.localTxId());

    Integer id = booking.getId();
    if (bookings.containsKey(id)) {
      bookings.get(id).cancel();
    }
  }
```